# Create a database migration to be applied before existing migrations (Yii 2)

Tags: yii2

When creating migrations in the Yii 2 framework they have a timestamp. I want to create a migration, which should be executed before the other existing migrations. When using the create tool this isn't possible. Is there a safe way to create a new migration which will be executed before all other migrations?

What I want to achieve is to create an initial migration that sets up the database. It has to be applied before all other migrations but it cannot because it will have a later time stamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "fake" the timestamp, just remember to change the class name acordingly.

Create a migration with CLI command

```
php yii migrate/create my_table_name
```

and change the file name and the 
class name and run `php yii migrate` it will all come together.

Comment: But what else do I have to fake: only one entry in the migration table?

Comment: if you create a migration with CLI command `pyp yii migrate/create my_table_name` and change the file name and the class name and run `php yii migrate` it will all come together.

Comment: The important bit it to fake the timestamp, give the migration you want to run first an earlier timestamp. Ensure the change is both in the file name and class name

Answer (score 0):

In the `migration` table, you could add your migration to be the first one by the *apply time* or changed it if there's already in the table.